# ExtJs: console returns Unrecognized alias: data.validator.presence in testing build

Tags: javascript, extjs6.2

I am making an application with extjs 6.2 after running app build testing and running the testing build, the console returns the error:

> Uncaught Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Unrecognized alias: data.validator.presence

I am aware this has something to do with the model for my login page yet I am not sure how to fix this.

Login page:

```
Ext.define('uber.view.login.Login',{
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    xtype: 'login',

    requires: [ 
       'uber.view.login.LoginController', 
       'uber.view.common.Radio', 
       'uber.view.main.Main',
       'uber.model.User',
       ],

    refernce: 'login',
    itemId: 'login',
    style: {
        'background-color': '#f4f4f4',
    },
    layout: 'fit',
    controller: 'login',
    abValue: '',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'container',
        layout: 'center',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            cls: 'panel-wrap',
            width: 500,
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'component',
                cls: 'title-component',
                html: '<a><h1 style="padding: 15px 30px 0;">UberTutor</h1></a>'
            },{
                xtype: 'panel',
                flex: 1,
                layout: 'fit',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'form',
                    reference: 'formpanel',
                    padding: 30,
                    items: [{
                        //Login/SignUp title
                        xtype: 'component',
                        itemId: 'title',
                        cls: 'inner-title-component',
                        html: '<h2>Sign Up</h2>',
                    },{
                        xtype: 'component',
                        html: '<hr>'
                    },{
                        xtype: 'pageradio',
                    },{
                        xtype: 'container',
                        layout: {
                            type: 'vbox',
                            align: 'stretch'
                        },
                        defaults: {
                            anchor: '100%',
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            submitEmptyText: false
                        },
                        items: [{
                            emptyText: 'Username',
                            name: 'username',
                            reference: 'username',
                        },{
                            emptyText: 'Email',
                            name: 'email'
                        },{
                            emptyText: 'Password',
                            name: 'password',
                            inputType: 'password'
                        },{
                            emptyText: 'Confirm Password',
                            name: 'password2',
                            inputType: 'password'
                        }]
                    },{
                        xtype: 'toolbar',
                        items: [{
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'Sign Up',
                            handler: 'loginPageStatus'
                        },'->',{
                            xtype: 'component',
                            html: '<a>Forgot username / password?</a>'
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
});
```

Login Controller

```
Ext.define('uber.view.login.LoginController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.login',

    setlogin: function () {
        var me = this;
        var status = me.lookupReference('pageradio');
        var radio = status.setValue({
            rb : 2
        });
    },

    loginPageStatus: function (){
        var me = this;
        var status = me.lookupReference('pageradio');
        var radio = status.getValue();

        if (radio.ab != '1') {
            this.login();
        } else {
            this.signup();
        }
    },

    onLoginFailure: function (form, action) {
        var me = this;
        this.getView().unmask();
        var result = uber.util.Util.decodeJSON(action.response.responseText);
        Ext.Msg.alert('Error', result.data, Ext.emptyFn);
    },

    onLoginSuccess: function (form, action) {
        var me = this;
        this.getView().unmask();
    //if login info is correct
        me.lookupReference('formpanel').up('login').destroy();
        Ext.create('uber.view.main.Main');

        // var mainCard = me.lookupReference('mainCardPanel');
        var mainCard = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#mainCardPanel')[0];
        // var cardItem = mainCard.getActiveItem;
        // var destory = cardItem.destroy();
        var card2 = mainCard.add(Ext.create('uber.view.main.MainPage'));
        var mainLayout = mainCard.getLayout();
        var card = mainCard.setActiveItem('mainpage');

        var result = uber.util.Util.decodeJSON(action.response.responseText);
        var userName = result.data.userName;
        var userNameText = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#userNameItemId')[0];
        userNameText.setText(userName);
    },

    login: function () {
        var me = this;
        var formPanel = this.lookupReference('formpanel');
        var model = Ext.create('uber.model.User', formPanel.getValues());
        var errors = model.validate();
        Ext.getBody().mask('Validating... Please Wait...');
        if(model.isValid()){
            formPanel.submit({ 
                url: '/uber2/main/login!login.action',
                method: 'POST', 
                clientValidation: true,
                scope: me,
                success: 'onLoginSuccess' ,
                failure: 'onLoginFailure' 
            });
        } else {
            var message = "";
            Ext.each(errors.items,function(rec){
                message +=rec.getMessage()+"<br>";
            });
            Ext.Msg.alert("Validation failed", message, Ext.emptyFn);
        }
    },

});
```

Validation Model for Login

```
Ext.define('uber.model.User',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    alias: 'model.user',

    fields: [

        { name: 'username', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'password', type: 'string' }        
    ],

    validators: {
        username: { type: 'presence', message: 'please input valid username' },
        password: { type: 'presence', message: 'please input valid password' }
    }
})
```

Some help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Require `Ext.data.validator.Presence` in your model.

Comment: That did the trick as well as a bit of a fix to how i wrote the code, but thanks